# Zygote cannot evaluate Hessian if the function argument is annotated

Tags: julia, automatic-differentiation

I am trying to calculate some Hessian matrix in Julia using Zygote package.
Consider the example below:

```
using Zygote
function test(x::Vector{Float64})
    return x[1]*x[2]
end
x0 = Vector{Float64}([1.,2.])
hessian(x->test(x), x0)
```

This will produces the error below:

```
MethodError: no method matching test(::Matrix{ForwardDiff.Dual{Nothing, Float64, 3}})

Closest candidates are:
  test(::Vector{Float64})
```

The issue is I annotated the argument of the function `test`. If I do not annotate, it will be fine. Is there a way to overcome this issue if I choose to annotate the function's argument?
Apart from code readability, I fear not making the argument's type clear might cause sub-optimal performance.

Answer (score 1):

`Zygote.hessian` uses ForwardDiff over Zygote, and hence needs functions to accept arrays of Dual numbers.

Narrow type annotations aren't helpful for performance. Plain `function test(x)` will compile exactly the same specialisations for `Vector{Float64}`. As will things like `test(x::AbstractVector{<:Real})` or just `test(x::AbstractVector)`, if you want to document your intentions, and ensure an error on mistakes like `test.([1,2,3])`.